# Change image name and store image problem in Laravel project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, image

I want to change the image name follow video id in Laravel project. But when I upload and save the image, save at database name become `/tmp/phpRXDHFh`, I want the image name save at database as `public/video/themnull/video-id.png`. How to solve this? And also using below code, the image did not store at `public/video/themnull` folder. I do not know where got problem.

Here is code of controller

```
if ($request->hasFile('video_path') != '') {

    $art_video = $request->file('video_path');
    $ad_video_name = uniqid('video_') . Str::random('10') . '.' . $art_video->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $created_id = 0;

    $video_image_path = $request->file('image_path');
    $video_image_name =  $art_video->id. '.' . $video_image_path->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $video_image_path_resize = Image::make($video_image_path->getRealPath());
     $video_image_path_resize->resize(400, 200);
    if ($video_image_path->isValid()) {

        $video_image_path_resize->save(public_path('video/themnull/' . $video_image_name));
        $video_image_path = 'public/video/themnull/' . $video_image_name;
        $data['image_path'] = $video_image_path;
    }
```

Comment: Hi James, can help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

use `move` function instead of `storeAs`

here is the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#copying-moving-files

```
something like below:

const PATH = 'your-address-in-public-folder';
$extention = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$filename = rand(111111, 999999) . "." . $image_extention;
$file->move($destination, $image_filename);
```

Comment: Hi, for the video store to server ok, just the image path.

Comment: From my code at controller, I do not know which part go problem.

Comment: you need to check your code when your condition is false and write logic for that to what are you gonna do when file is not valid because problem occurs when the file is not valid and you set temporary url of file

Comment: you remove all your function but I think, you save the file even if it's not valid!

Comment: remove function? no....sorry I finish time use Laravel

Comment: So how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't familiar with your method of saving the image. I will show you how I usually practice. Usually I will create new variable for the name, lets say like this:

```
$video_image_name = "public/video/themnull/video-id.png";
```

or if you want to add the id:

```
$video_image_name = "public/video/themnull/".$art_video->id.".png";
```

Then I will save it by calling the model. For example my model is MyImage that contain field name 'newName' and 'path'. This is how I save it:

```
MyImage::create([
     'newName'=> $video_image_name,
     'path'   => "public/video/themnull". $video_image_name,
]);
```